# Forcing Installshield to install SQL Server CE before it will install main application

Tags: installation, sql-server-ce, windows-installer, installshield

Any clue how to force Installshield to install SQL Server CE *before* it will install the main application?

(SQL Server CE is included in the installation project)

Thanks!

Comment: Hav you considered private deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of InstallShield and project type are you using?  You probably want to configure your prerequisite as a "setup prerequisite"  that gets ran by setup.exe prior to your main installer UI.

Comment: Sorry but what do u mean about project type? I build setup.exe

Comment: It's kind of a big deal to know your project type.  If you were in .NET,  I'd think you want to know if you were creating a console app,  winforms app,  WPF app, windows service and so on.  You wouldn't just say  "I'm building an EXE".